# Why do I continue to receive PHP Deprecated errors despite this ini setting?

Tags: php, vbulletin, error-reporting, bitmask

I've set my error_reporting to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT
```

in php.ini. The numerical value according to phpinfo() is 22527.

However we are still logging plenty of

```
[01-Oct-2011 13:06:36] PHP Deprecated:  Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /htdocs/www/site/core.php on line 2381
[01-Oct-2011 13:06:36] PHP Deprecated:  Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /htdocs/www/site/core.php on line 1538
```

I've seen a few other questions about this, but not with any solutions I haven't tried. We're using (an outdated version of) VBulletin. Could that be changing the setting?

I see now that VBulletin's forumdisplay.php has a line

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Commenting this out didn't change anything.

Comment: Look around for some debug setting in the backend. I've ran into the same issue with things like Magento and Drupal.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Just a note: `E_ALL & ~(E_DEPRECATED|E_STRICT)` should be equal to what you're using and is a bit more consistent in its syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might help (if you're interested in doing your own handler): http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.examples.php

Comment: Thanks for the comments... we're on PHP 5.3.8.

Comment: Did you restart your webserver after making the ini change?

Comment: @Cups I can't, it's on shared hosting. Other ini changes seem to take place immediately, like when I change display_errors, so... hmm. Not sure.